# Android: Como abrir PDF sem usar da internet?

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf, app

Como faço para colocar um arquivo `.pdf` no próprio `app`, e abri-lo sem precisar baixar usando a URL dele? Seria tudo offline. Assim que o app fosse instalado, o `.pdf` iria junto com ele.

Answer (score 1):

O Android não tem suporte para formato PDF, para isso é necessário utilizar bibliotecas externas. Uma bastante utilizada é a [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library).

Abaixo segue o passo a passo para utilizar ela

> 1) Add PdfViewer.jar into your project's build path
>
> 2) Copy the following drawable resources from PdfViewer/res/drawable
>   into YourProject/res/drawable
>        left_arrow.png
>        right_arrow.png
>        zoom_in.png
>        zoom_out.png
>
> 3) Copy the following layout resources from PdfViewer/res/layout into
>   YourProject/res/layout
>        dialog_pagenumber.xml
>        pdf_file_password.xml
>
> 4) Derive your PDF activity from
>   net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity
>
> 5) Using the default drawables and layouts:
>        public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }
>        public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }
>        public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
>        public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }
>        public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }
>        public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
>        public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
>        public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
>        public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
>        public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
>
> 6) Invoke your PdfViewActivity derived with the following code:
>        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourPdfViewerActivity.class);
>        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE");
>        startActivity(intent);

Fonte: [README.txt](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)